# How to use pre-existing threat catalogue to determine if a certain system is vulnerable?

Tags: vulnerability, risk-analysis, threat-modeling, threats

There are many risk assessment guidelines such NIST800-30 and ISO 27005 that provide a catalogue of known threats as reference. Using a qualitative approach, I selected one threat events catalogue and I tried to select the threats that are applicable to my use case.

To my understanding, by studying the system design specifications, I can compile a list of threats that **may** affect the system. However, I want to be more deterministic in my approach and say **if** the system is vulnerable to my compiled threats or not.

My approach is to look at the current security controls deployed on the system, and by analysing these controls I can say "System is vulnerable to threat X, Y and Z". I know I kind of have an answer to my question, but maybe there is a more methodological / organized approach? Having a list of known threats, how can I determine if a system is vulnerable or not?

PS: I am more interested on a qualitative approach, I know a vulnerability tool can make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about a pure risk assessment methodology. And it's quite simple at a high level.

- what are the inherent, relevant risks in the context (vulnerabilities matched with threats)?
- what controls are in place to address those risks?
- how effective are those controls against those risks?
- what's left that is unaddressed?

Threat catalogues are meant to help inspire thoughts to come up with a list of relevant risks in context. They are not meant to be a complete list.

Vulnerability tools look at *technical risks* that are discoverable through technical analysis. There is a whole universe of risk that is outside of technical vulnerabilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @schroeder and I agree with you about the purpose of threat catalogues. How can I evaluate the effectiveness of the existing controls?

Comment: You said you wanted a qualitative assessment. You determine the scale you want and assess based on that scale. H/M/L, Primary/Secondary/Tertiary control, etc.